# -split ' ' that works locally in Powershell does not work in a Azure pipeline Powershell task

Tags: git, powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am using git diff command to get the file that changed between the last 2 commits and based on the action have to do different things with the files. So I have to extract the action on the file and the filename.

**For a renamed file:**

The result of git diff command is the below which is a renamed swagger file from `swaggerA.json` to `swaggerB.json`

> R100 swaggerA.json swaggerB.json

This is my code:

```
$files=$(git diff HEAD~ HEAD --name-status) 
$temp=$files -split ' '
echo $temp 
echo $temp.Length
$name=$temp[1]
echo "this is $name file"
write-host $name 
$output=$name.Split(' ')
$length=$output.Length
$output[0] 
$output[1] 
$output[$length-1]
```

The above script should’ve ideally split and provided 3 parts as:

1) R100

2) swaggerAjson

3) swaggerB.json

But it doesn’t do that in the Powershell task of Azure pipeline, and gives the whole string each time.

Comment: I don't really understand the part where you try to split the `$name` variable (which now should store `swaggerA.json`) into a new variable `$output`. This will result in a one element string array `swaggerA.json`. Should this be a return value from a function? If so, just do `return ,$temp`. (mind the unary comma operator)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`git diff [cid]..[cid] --name-status` outputs lines of tab-separated values, so splitting on a normal space won't help you:

```
$changes = git diff HEAD~ HEAD --name-status |ForEach-Object {
    # split on tab "`t"
    $change,$orig,$new = $_ -split "`t"
    [pscustomobject]@{
        Change = $change
        Original = $orig
        Current = $new
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That the output is tab-separated values and needs to be split on `t helped to split that string.

Answer (score 3):

Because the `gid diff` returnes a string with hidden ASCII symbol (`` `t ``), if we copy the results to Notepad++ (and in the settings we press on 'Show all characters') we can see it:

[image]

So we need to replace it with regular space before the split:

```
$files = $files -replace '[^\p{L}\p{Nd}/(/./_]', ' '
```

Now it will work and you will get the string splitted :)

Comment: Thank you! it was the `t that needed to be used to split the string!